# The correct way to "swap" a component in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make it  so that when a user clicks something on my GUI (it's irrelevant what), one `JTable` will disappear and another `JComponent` will replace it.

At the minute I am using the following code, where `contentPanel` is the `JPanel` I set as the `JFrame`'s content pane:

```
contentPanel.remove(table);
contentPanel.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPanel.updateUI();
```

which works perfectly, but I just want to confirm that this is the correct method. I mean, I can't think of any other way to achieve it but that doesn't necessarily mean anything and if there's an better way to do it, in terms of performance or anything, I like to know about it...

Comment: But the comment is wrong. You should NOT use updateUI() (I don't know how to down vote a comment or I would have). I have no idea where people keep getting the idea to use updateUI(). It is frwoned upon in every forum I belong to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, that is NOT the way to do it. You should never invoke updateUI(). Read the API, that method is only used when you change the LAF.

After adding/removing components you should do:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

> (it's irrevelevant what), one JTable will disappear and another JComponent will replace it.

Maybe it is relevant. Usually a JTable is displayed in a JScrollPane. So maybe a better solution is to use:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( anotherComponent );
```

then the scrollpane will do the validation for you.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have changed my code and it still works. Apart from that little issue, is there anything else that I must change in my code?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that is also rather useful to know as well!

Comment: Though FYI, the component that I said was irrelevant was actually the component that the user clicked, and not was was displayed (or removed)!

Comment: Yes, I read the question wrong, the point I was trying to make there was more about the replacing of components in a scrollpane, not on the component that was clicked.

Answer (score 8):

A better way is to use a CardLayout, and add both tables, then just display the correct card/table.

Comment: That's just preference though, isn't it? OR will it effect the performance of my code drastically?

Comment: CardLayout is handy when you replace an entier panel with multiple components on each panel. That is whenever you see code use the replaceAll() method it is a candidate for a CardLayout. When using a CardLayout both cards are in memory at the same time so it will use extra memory.

Comment: @camickr: Will CardLayout use more memory even if I were to initialise both components? When you  add components to a JPanel does it use more memory then?

Comment: If you allocate memory for all components then memory usage will be similiar. The point I was trying to make is that the CardLayout can only determine the size to use when all panels have been created and added to the card layout. When you swap panels they still remain in memory. When you remove/replace components they may be garbage collected if they are no longer used.

Comment: @camickr Okay, thanks. I think I'll accept your answer but I thank Kylar for his answer too.